# How to only make part of a go document show up in godocs

Tags: go, documentation, godoc

I am using godocs to document my API written in go/golang and I am documenting it using godocs in the sense that I generate an HTML page of my entire main.go file which contains all the functions used to create my API. However, I do not want to display information about all my helper functions, I just want to display header information about some functions in the file. Is there a way to only allow some of the functions in the file to be part of the documentation or do I have to create another file for all my helper functions?
Right now I am testing it on my local port 8000: `godoc -http=:8000`

Comment: Your helper functions shouldn't need to be exported, thus wouldn't be part of the docs.

Comment: My helper functions are in the same file though. Do I need to move them to a separate file?

Comment: No. Exported members begin with a capital letter, unexported ones begin with a lower-case letter (ref: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers). You should simply start the helpers with a lower case and they will be omitted from your docs, unless you add a flag to specifically also include unexported members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *default* behavior of the commands **godoc** and its cousin **go doc**, display package documentation of *exported declarations*. Oddly I did not find a simple authoritative source to link to that explicitly documents this fact, but there are inferences to that fact referenced in commands that alter the default behavior, such as from the [godoc package's documentation](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc):

> The presentation mode of web pages served by godoc can be controlled with the "m" URL parameter; it accepts a comma-separated list of flag names as value:

...

> For instance, http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/?m=all,text shows the documentation for all (not just the exported) declarations of package big, in textual form (as it would appear when using godoc from the command line: "godoc -src math/big .*").

And the source code at https://golang.org/src/go/doc/doc.go which includes:

```
81    const (
82        // extract documentation for all package-level declarations,
83        // not just exported ones
84        AllDecls Mode = 1 << iota
...
89    )
```

And https://golang.org/src/go/doc/exports.go documents a function with:

```
241    // fileExports removes unexported declarations from src in place.
```

And finally running `go doc -h` in the terminal reveals a flag:

*-u show unexported symbols as well as exported.*